# Why "selected" not rendered here?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand how React works with the new Hooks implementation. In this example, I want the browsers to render selected items as I click on the rendered options. But as you can see, it doesn't work.

Here is the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pjorxzyrx7

Do I have to use the useEffect in this case? Also, as I understand, useEffect couldn't render anything and only return functions. So, what am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use external links to show your code. Instead, please [edit] your question to also include a [mcve] of your code *in the question itself* (using [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), no images please!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently mutating the contents of the `selected` array instead of replacing it.  React can't detect a state change when you do this.

Try something like the following:

```
  const handleSelected = item => {
    console.log(item);
    console.log(selected);
    setSelected([...selected, item]);
  };
```

When updating arrays or objects as a part of a state, always make a new copy to assign so that React can properly know when to re-render.

Also, include relevant parts of your code directly in the question in the future, instead of hiding it behind a link (although including a runnable example is great!)